# 要素の横並びが指定通りになりません（float:left;）

Tags: css

rightcontentに配置した二枚の画像を右側の枠に広告のような形で入れたいです。
mainとrightcontentのグループに分けてfloat:left;を用いて右への回り込みをさせようと思いましたがサルの画像のブロックが下にずれてしまい二枚の画像も横へ行きません。

marginによる横幅の問題かとも思いましたがmarginを消しても変化しませんでした。原因と解決方法を知りたいです。

カラムレイアウト有
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Banana design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="top.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!----header------>
    <div class="top-head">
      <div class="content">
          <h1>Banana Design</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!----header----->
    <!----nav bar------>
    <nav>
        <ul class="top-nav">
            <li class="list-border"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">ホーム</a></li>
            <li class="list-border"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">組織概要</a></li>
            <li class="list-border"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">事業内容</a></li>
            <li class="list-border"></li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
        
    </nav>
    <!----nav bar------>
    <!---main content-->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="leftcontent">
            <div class="maincontent">
            
               <div class="box">
                  <div class="titleback">
                     <h2 class="title">NEWS</h2>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="boxcontent">
                   <ul class="contentul">
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27 
                       <a href="#" class="tag">service</a> 
                       <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">serviece</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="contentli">2022/01/27
                        <a href="#" class="tag">service</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text">BANANAに今秋の新商品が登場！</a>
                     </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="maincontent2">
                <div class="box2">
                    <div class="titleback2">
                       <h3 class="title">About Us</h3>
                   </div>
                   <div class="boxcontent2">
                       <img class="contentimg" src="https://cyllabus-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/course_image/image/2296/5e5c1c7e-ae9a-4e98-adfd-480175052663.png" alt="">
                       <p>バナナとは"バナナを食べるくらいならバナナになれ。"をモットーにバナナで世界に凹みをいれるその日まで戦い続ける組織である。</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        
           <div class="maincontent3">
                <div class="box3">
                    <div class="titleback3">
                       <h3 class="title">Services</h3> 
                   </div>
                   <div class="boxcontent3">
                       <img class="contentimg" src="https://cyllabus-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/course_image/image/2297/e62a4514-c1bb-4e74-a9da-9bebc2cebf33.png" alt="">
                       <p>バナナではあらゆるクリエイティブ事業に挑戦しています。</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--main content-->
    <!--left content-->
    <div class="rightcontent">
        <div><img  src="https://cyllabus-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/course_image/image/2329/a80f1b30-2675-4e79-91cf-158f1038204e.jpg" alt=""></div><!--img:インライン要素だから横がデフォルト。divにしてブロック要素にする-->
        <div><img  src="https://cyllabus-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/course_image/image/2331/ef7fe7dc-3bfc-4017-989a-86c78deabc06.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 149, 0.575);
  z-index: 0;
}

/*----------header-------------*/
.top-head {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;

  background: url(https://cyllabus-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/course_image/image/3145/e7d27adf-1c78-4ed4-b3c6-f62eaa27232e.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.content {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-head h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(52, 85, 43, 0, 8); /* X. Y. 半径*/
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

/*----------------header-------------*/
/*-----------nav---------------*/
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-nav {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #856727),
    color-stop(1, #6a511f)
  );
}

.top-nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 3px rgba(52, 85, 43, 0.8);
} /*top-bottomへのグラデーション*/

.top-nav li {
  float: left; /*ulに指定しても横並びにならない*/
}

.clear {
  clear: both; /*flaotの回り込みによってcssが効かないことがある。その時はfloatを指定した次の要素にclear:bothを指定して回り込みを解除する*/
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  display: block; /*linkはinline要素だからblock要素にすることでmargin/widthが効くようにしている*/
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, #856727),
    color-stop(1, #6a511f)
  );
}

a {
  text-decoration: none; /*linkタグについてるデフォルトのアンダーラインを削除*/
}

.nav-link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-border {
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(49, 25, 0, 0.7);
  height: 60px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/*----------------nav----------------*/
/*------------------main---------------*/
.main {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.maincontent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: white;
}
.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.boxcontent {
  margin: 0;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.contentul {
  list-style: none;
}
.tag {
  background-color: rgba(15, 128, 15, 0.336);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.title {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.tag .text {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contentli {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*--------------------main----------------------*/
/*------------------main-small-------------------*/
.maincontent2,
.maincontent3 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: white;
  float: left;
}

.maincontent2 {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.titleback2,
.titleback3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
}

.boxcontent2,
.boxcontent3 {
  height: 220px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.contentimg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
}
/*-------------------main-small-------------------*/

/*-----------------right content------------------*/

.rightcontent img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
}
.main,
.rightcontent {
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
　margin-right:40px;
}
```

Comment: `float:flex;`とは何でしょうか？ソースコードにもCSSでもそういった値は出てきません。display:flexの間違いですかね？

Comment: @keitaro_so すみません。float:left;の間違いです‼　訂正します！

Comment: ちなみに最終的なカラムレイアウト案はどんな感じでしょうか？図でかつ実際の要素名(#main,#leftcontents等)でいただけるとわかりやすいです。[参考例](https://www.attend.jp/desine_170829)

Comment: ＠keitaro_so 　追加しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

全体をボックスとして捉えるのがいいと思います。よくあるのだと

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main">
        main content
    </div>

    <div class="small-box">
      <div class="small-box__left">
         smallbox1
      </div>
      <div class="small-box__right">
         smallbox1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-content">
      <div class="right-content">
         right-content
      </div>
      <div class="right-content">
         right-content
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cssでいうと

```
.wrapper {
  clear: both;
}
.main-content {
   float: left;
}
.side-content {
   float: right;
}
```

こんなのりで

`clear: both`で覆った内側にfloat:right, float: leftを使う感じです。（floatを使うなら）

```
.small-box {
  clear: both;
}

.small-box__left {
  float: left;
}
.small-box__right {
  float: right;
}
```

最近でいうとgridを使うのが流行りなんじゃないかとは思います。

https://webdesign-trends.net/entry/11086

参考にしてください。

Comment: ＠ShengboXu　回答ありがとうございます！いったん既存のfloat:left;を削除してfloat:left; float:right;をそれぞれにかけなおしてみたのですが画像がサルのブロックの下に回り込んでしまいます。デベロッパーツールでみるとmainの右側がオレンジになっているのですがmainのmarginは０にしているのでどこのmarginなのかが不明です。原因おわかりになりますでしょうか？